# How can I approve kubernetes certificate signing request using ansible

Tags: kubernetes, ansible

I am using `ansible`, and I have created a valid `CertificateSigningRequest` in my `kubernetes` cluster. After that, I need to approve it with something like `kubectl certificate approve myuser`, but using `ansible`.

I can do it with `command` module and the task below.

```
- name: 'Approve csr for myuser'
  ansible.builtin.command:
    cmd: 'kubectl certificate approve myuser'
```

But maybe there is some ansible module crafted for this specific situation.

There is the possibility that it could be done with the help of [kubernetes.core.k8s_json_patch](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/kubernetes/core/k8s_json_patch_module.html#ansible-collections-kubernetes-core-k8s-json-patch-module) module, but currently I can't figure out how.

Please keep in mind that the task should be idempotent.

Answer (score 2):

> There is the possibility that it could be done with the help of kubernetes.core.k8s_json_patch module, but currently I can't figure out how.

You can't do this with the JSON patch module because an approval doesn't involve making any changes to the certificate request itself; you need to `PUT` to the approval API endpoint. If you run `kubectl -v8 certificate approve <csr_name>`, you'll see:

```
PUT https://127.0.0.1:37451/apis/certificates.k8s.io/v1/certificatesigningrequests/<csr_name>/approval
```

You could do that using the `uri` module, but you would need to set up the authentication header yourself.

It's probably much easier to simply use the `kubectl` command as you have shown in your question.